# Incorrect line number returned on specifying Start parameter in enumerate Python

Tags: python

I have slight confusion regarding the start parameter in enumerate function,as i recently started working on python i don't have much idea how it is supposed to work.
Suppose i have an example file below:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

This is the first line `[SB WOM]|[INTERNAL REQUEST]|[START]` which is the start of message

```
Name : Vaibhav
Designation : Technical Lead
ID : 123456
Company : Nokia
```

This is the sixth line `[SB WOM]|[INTERNAL REQUEST]|[END]` which is the end of message

Now when i run the below code :

```
path =("C:/Users/vgupt021/Desktop")
in_file = os.path.join(path,"KSClogs_Test.txt")
fd = open(in_file,'r')
for linenum,line in enumerate(fd) :
    if "[SB WOM]|[INTERNAL REQUEST]|[START]" in line:
        x1 = linenum
        print x1
        break 
for linenum,line in enumerate(fd,x1):
    if "[SB WOM]|[INTERNAL REQUEST]|[END]" in line:
        print linenum
        break
```

I get the linenum returned as 3 and 7, I am not clear why it is not returned as 3,8.Since the index number of line `"[SB WOM]|[INTERNAL REQUEST]|[END]"` is 8 and not 7, how the start parameter makes the difference in second part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file iterator object has read the first four lines, when running the second `for` loop, it starts from where it stopped. The previous iteration stopped at line 3 (assuming we start counting from 0), the next for loop starts at line 4.

Therefore, the `enumerate` of the second loop should start from `x1 + 1` not `x1` as the line with index `x1` was already covered in the previous loop; last line of first loop:

```
for linenum, line in enumerate(fd, x1+1):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Moses for the quick reply.Can you also help me with the scenario for the above mentioned case asssuming it is a very large file which has above mentioned lines and if i give the input as "ID = 123456", i should get all the line  from "START" to "END" get printed.

Comment: I think it's better if you post this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
x = range(10)
for i, e in enumerate(x):
    if i == 4:
        print i
        st = i
        break

for i, e in enumerate(x, st):
    print i
```

And you will see this output:

```
4
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

So, what does the second parameter of `enumerate`? Well, it's the starting value of the index of `enumerate`. The iterable variable `x` is enumerated again from the beginning but the values of `i` at different iteration is shifted by the value of `st`.

Instead of having the values of `i` as 0, 1, 2, etc., we have 4, 5, 6, etc.

I think that explains why you have the incorrect line number in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a brilliant explanation, definitely it makes me to understand how the code works.Can you also help me with the scenario for the above mentioned case assuming it is a very large file which has above mentioned lines somewhere in the file and if I give the input as "ID = 123456", i should get all the lines from "START" to "END" get printed.